# Node Langauge needs to be undefinde by default

Tags: i18n-l10n

my website (Drupal 7) is available in German (?q=de) and English (?q=en) (i18n Module). Users can create own pins (nodes) (similar to pinterest). The default language of the website is set to german. So everytime somebody creates a new pin (node) the language of the pin is set to german.

The problem is, if somebody is using the english (?q=en) version and clicks on a pin he gets redirected to the german version (?q=de).

I can manually set the language of each pin to undefined. Then everybody stays on the right version, but this would be to much work to do, to change the language of each pin all the time.

I can't let the users chose the Language, because every pin needs to be set to undefinded.

How can I achive, that with every new pin the language is set to undefined automatically?

Comment: If there is not an English translation of the German node then they should see the German version, based on what you said. However, you can use views along with a language contextual filter to only show the proper version of node lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "Structure" > "Content types" editing page (`/admin/structure/types/manage/article` — replace `article` to your *pin* content-type), you can switch on (=tick) `Set current language as default for new content` in the `Extended language options` sub-section in the `Multilingual settings` tab (near the bottom-left).  Then when a user visiting your website is in the English mode and creates a new node (pin?), the language of the node will be English.

It is not Language neutral, but that may be what you can accept?